# Need formula to rearrange the data

Tags: excel

I have 3 columns in Excel.

`Column A` and `Column B` have identical data (but re-arranged). `Column C` is the corresponding value of `Column B`.

I would like to match values of `Column C` to `Column A`. Basically looking to re-arrange data. Please help me with the formula.

```
-A-  -B-  -C-
ID   ID   Name  Re-Arrange (How I need)
101  105  Ron   Lou
102  104  jack  bill
103  102  Bill  Amy
104  103  Amy   Jack
105  101  Lou   Ron
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `VLOOKUP`.  For example, in cell `D2`, put this formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,B$2:C$6,2,0)
```

That will:

1. look at the value in cell `A2` (**101** in this case);
2. find it in the first column of the range `B2:C6` (i.e., find it in `B2:B6`);
3. return the corresponding value in the `2`nd column of that same range (i.e., column `C2:C6` of the range `B2:C6`)
4. the fourth parameter, `0`, means only allow an exact match.